# How to delete all information belonging to an ejabberd vhost?

Tags: virtualhost, user-accounts, ejabberd, gdpr

Deactivating an *ejabberd* vhost is easy. In the simplest case, just remove the entry from the `hosts` section in `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml`.

I presume this does not delete any information about the users related to that host:

- Username
- Password (if not taken from LDAP or similar)
- vcard
- Roster
- Offline Messages
- MAM Archive

and probably a few things more still remain in the Mnesia database.

How can I get rid of this information for an entire vhost?

Answer (score 2):

With a command like this:

```
$ ejabberdctl delete_old_users_vhost localhost 0
Deleted 2 users: [{<<"hag66">>,<<"localhost">>},
  {<<"user1">>,<<"localhost">>}]
```

Comment: One step in the right direction. But I would like it per-vhost. Without that limit, it also deletes all the TURN accounts. Maybe I can work around this with the `protect_old_users` configuration setting?

Comment: It does not seem to affect users who are authenticated against an external authentication source; only local user accounts seem to be affected.